# Is there an alternative to "node" return type?

Tags: java

So I'm doing a javafx assignment that involves GUI stuff.. One of the methods in code is:

```
private Node create(Stage Stage1) {
TabPane tp = new TabPane();
tp.prefWidthProperty().bind(Stage1.widthProperty());
tbApp.setClosable(false);
tbPerson.setContent(createPersonContent());
tbApp.setContent(createAppointmentsContent());
tp.getTabs().addAll(tbPerson, tbApp);   
return tp;
}
```

My question is, is the "node" really necessary? Can I name this a different method type? As we haven't really learned what node is in class.

Comment: Since `tp` is a `TabPane`, the return type can be anything `TabPane` is *assignment-compatible* with, i.e. any base class or implemented interface.

Comment: A course that teaches people to build complex windows without teaching what a [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is seems backward to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a method here and the Node is the return type of the method. Node is a basic javafx.scene object. This is a broad statement saying that you are returning a javafx object of some sort in this method. You could improve the accuracy of this method by changing it to `private TabPane create(Stage stage1)` You can also read about the Node object [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).